# How to fill font-awesome after click on the font-awesome icon?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a font-awesome icon but when i had clicked on the icon he has to be filled, yet he is only outlined

Html

```
<center><span id="timesClicked">0</span></center>

<i class="fa fa-heart-o btn btn-default" onclick="javascript:btnClick()"></i>
```

Javascript

```
var timesClicked = 0;

function btnClick() {
timesClicked++;

document.getElementById('timesClicked').innerHTML = timesClicked;
return true
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7ghbhtcf/

Comment: Your fiddle doesn’t work, you need to wrap the JS in the head here, because you are using the function name in the HTML part - https://jsfiddle.net/7ghbhtcf/6/ And what is the actual problem/question here then? If you want to have a filled heart, then you need to switch out the class ...

Comment: The fiddle works on my computer. My question is: How to change the color on the font-awesome heart after cliked on it?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7ghbhtcf/7/

Comment: @Mohammad your code works thanx!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fill the heart icon you need to swap classes (remove `fa-heart-o` and add `fa-heart`):

```js
var timesClicked = 0;

function btnClick() {
  timesClicked++;
  if (timesClicked === 1) {
    var elem = document.querySelector('i');
    elem.classList.remove('fa-heart-o');
    elem.classList.add('fa-heart');
  }
  document.getElementById('timesClicked').innerHTML = timesClicked;
  return true
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<center><span id="timesClicked">0</span></center>

<i class="fa fa-heart-o btn btn-default" onclick="javascript:btnClick()"></i>
```

Please also note that you should not use the `<center>` element as it [no longer exists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center).